# Sitecore Personalization Implementation

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I am developing a website lets say a vehicle related site in which we have 3 vehicles

1. `Bicycle`
2. `Moterbikes`
3. `Cars`

On the home page I am displaying one item each (`Bicycle`, `Moterbike`, `Car`). In sitecore I need to use personalization in such a manner if user visited our site previously and he navigated on `Bicycles` section most, it means user is interested in `Bicycles` and if he is a anonymous user and if he come to our website again I need to show 3 `Bicycles` (instead of 1 `Bicycle` 1 `Motorbike` and 1 `Car`) on the home page.

What should I need to do in Sitecore DMS?

Kind Regards,
AP

Answer (score 0):

You can 'personalize' a rendering in the presentation details. Then, using rules you can select whatever rules you want to apply. This then is a condition and you can change the content that needs to be shown.
Example: [image]

In this small default example you see the default situation below, and above it a new condition that shows different content if the rule condition is met. I just selected a default rule, you should probably create one to match your own requirements.

You can find this screen by going to your presentation details, selecting a rendering and clicking 'Personalize' on the right.
or using the Page Editor by selecting a component and clicking 'Personalize component'.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As you move into future phases of personalization too you can leverage **predictive personalization** to continue to tailor the content to that particular user in real-time. If you were to create pattern cards for each of the vehicle types, the visitor would be matched to in real-time to a pattern card and shown the content that's related to that pattern. For example, if a user clicks through a number of bicycle pages and then starts exploring cars the content will update to show more car-related content. This content will continue to shift as the visitor explore more on the site.